# Codeigniter pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

in my controllers folder I have a file Migrate.php with the following method :

```
function drop_db($db_name){

    if ($this->dbforge->drop_database($db_name))
    {
        echo "Database {$db_name} deleted!";

    }
}
```

When called I need it to drop the database, however I get the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        ErrorException
Message:     pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
```

I tried to close the connexion using `$this->db->close();` at the beginning of my method but I still get the same error!

Comment: Did you try connecting to another database? as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502401/postgres-drop-database-error-pq-cannot-drop-the-currently-open-database

Comment: As @MehdiBounya noted, you'll need to connect to another db, and a typical db to connect to for administrative actions is the "admin" `postgres` database that should be created by default in your Postgres cluster.

Comment: @bma can I switch/connect to another database on the fly, just before executing `$this->dbforge->drop_database($db_name)` ?

Comment: Nothing on the Postgres side prevents changing databases on the fly. You'll need to look at the PHP connection docs, but I can't imagine that it would be difficult to do.

Comment: @bma I am asking if there is a codeigniter way to abstract that, am creating a library and I would like to support not only postgres but other db drivers

Comment: That's outside of my domain, I'm sorry I can't answer that.