# How to drop a test database after having run all tests?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, database-migration, dbmigrate

I am using the npm package db-migrate in my node-application to perform database migrations on a postgres database. I have an extra test-database, which I want to drop after having run all my tests. For this purpose, I added the following script to my package.json:

```
"test": "set ENV=test&& npx tsc && db-migrate --env test up && jasmine && db-migrate db:drop --env test test_database_name"
```

Doing so, I run into the following error:

```
 Error: Failed to drop database! error: cannot drop the currently open database
```

I have assumed the error would be due to the fact that I was connected to my test-database using the database adminsitration tool of my IDE (Intellij). The error keeps showing up, though, when both deactivating the connection to my test-database or removing it from my database-administration tool.

Therefore, I have tried the following alternative:

```
"test": "set ENV=test&& npx tsc && db-migrate --env test up && jasmine && db-migrate --env test reset"
```

From what I know, the last command of this test-script will drop the test-database, create it again and run all migrations.

It seems to be working correctly, I can remain connected to the test-database with the database-administration tool, all tables are dropped. However, in the end, the only table left in my test-database is a migrations table, which is empty. Why would it be empty? I was expecting to see all the migrations in it that were run after the database was recreated.

Comment: What happens when you disconnect your IDE from the db (also try closing your IDE)? Try disconnecting before the drop runs.

Comment: When I disconnect my IDE from the database and run the test-script, the tests are executed and it is stated that the test database has been successfully deleted. Just like before. When I reconnect to my database though, it is still there. Maybe I am missing the rights to delete the database. I don't know. Just out of curiosity though: Is this common practice, to delete the test database after having completed all tests?

Comment: When (trying) to drop an open database, this error is expected: [ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502401/postgres-drop-database-error-pq-cannot-drop-the-currently-open-database)

Comment: You might need to share more information on the script that is taking care of: `When I run this script, I am informed that the database called "test" has been successfully deleted`

Comment: Hi Luuk, thx for your help! The script that I am referring to is simply the script from my package.json and is the one given in the question. 
I do get the error, which you refer to, when I am trying to actively drop my database from within my IDE, but I don't see any error when executing my test-script.

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope it is a bit clearer now.